# docker-compose run with isolated sets of services?

Tags: testing, docker, concurrency, docker-compose

I have the following setup:

```
db:
  image: postgres:latest

app:
  ...
  links:
    - db
```

When I try to run `docker-compose run app testcommand` twice, it reuses the db container. Is it possible to make app create another db container?

What I'm after is:

- app_run_1 ---> db_1
- app_run_2 ---> db_2

I'm trying to isolate the services in order to run tests concurrently.

Comment: You might be able to use the -p flag to indicate a different project name: `docker-compose -p test1 run app testcommand` and `docker-compose -p test2 run app testcommand` should each have their own linked container instances.

Comment: I run into this issue as well. It seems, it's impossible to leverage docker-compose to run isolated sets of services, at least for now

Answer (score 0):

You can run isolated docker-compose services using `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` env variable.

All commands respect that env variable, and use different containers prefix.

```
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME="app1" docker-compose run --rm app bash
Creating network "app1_default" with the default driver
Creating app1_db_1
$ docker-compose stop
Stopping app1_db_1 ... done
```